# Alternatives to maven-jxr

Tags: java, documentation-generation

I'm currently using `maven-jxr` to generate .html file for each java file in a project. However the project seems to be pretty much abandonware with bug tracker lingering with feature requests WITH provided patches that nobody bothered to read/comment on. I need to extend its functionality for my needs and I was wondering if there exists any alive project, providing similar features or should I just fork it and start adding functionality?

Comment: Perhaps you could fork it and apply those patches? (so said the lazy commenter)  =)

Comment: Already done so... Afaik patches similar to mine are pending in some bug reports from years ago..

https://github.com/ContemplateLtd/libJXR

Comment: It's been updated, http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/jxr/ - as it's hosted under maven don't think it was ever abandonware, possibly just forgottenware.  The latest version has support for footers.  But still seems neglected http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JXR